# Can't set attribute from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to set some attribute values from ajax-jquery here some codes :

```
HTML_CODE
==========================================================================
<div class="col">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-end">
    <li id="cohort_x1" class="nav-item" data-toggle="chart" data-target="#chart" data-update="">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link py-2 px-3" data-toggle="tab">
        <span class="d-none d-md-block">CEI</span>
        <span class="d-md-none">W</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li id="cohort_x2" class="nav-item" data-toggle="chart" data-target="#chart" data-update="">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link py-2 px-3" data-toggle="tab">
        <span class="d-none d-md-block">CEI</span>
        <span class="d-md-none">W</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then the Javascript / AJAX Code

```js
$("#cohort_x1").click(function(){
    alert("Cohort X1 Clicked");
    // This code works, if place here --> $("#cohort_x1").attr("data-update","{'data':{'datasets':[{'data':[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000]},{'data':[20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000]}]}}");

    $.ajax({
        url     : url_target+"cohort_for_x1.php",
        type    : "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        cache   : false,              // To unable request pages to be cached
        success : function(data)      // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
            alert(data);
            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            $("#cohort_x1").attr("data-update","{'data':{'datasets':[{'data':[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000]},{'data':[20000, 30000, 40000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 80000]}]}}");
            $("#cohort_x1").attr("data-update",'{"data":{"datasets":[{"data":result.data1},{"data":result.data2}]}}');
        }
    });
    
});
```

Here the result from my ajax :

1. Using Alert

- alert(data); --> {"date":"2021-04-13","data1":["10000", "20000", "30000", "40000", "50000", "60000", "70000"],"data2":["20000", "30000", "40000", "50000", "60000", "70000", "80000"]}
- alert(result); --> [object Object]
- alert(result.data1); --> 10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000
- alert(result.data1[0]); --> 10000

2. Using Console.log

- console.log(result) --> {date: "2021-04-13", data1: Array(7), data2: Array(7)}
- inspect/tab_network --> status : 200, in preview also appear

The return of cohort_for_x1.php work fine and they return the array values that i needed.
When I placing the $("#cohort_x1").attr(...) before the ajax, the code works fine BUT when i put it inside the Ajax it doesnt works.

============================ NEW UPDATE ============================

Here the picture of console that i got, the left is the return when I place $("#cohort_x1").attr("data-update",....) **OUTSIDE of ajax**. The right is the return when I place $("#cohort_x1").attr("data-update",....) **INSIDE of ajax**.

The different is on the "update", the left contain the change, but the right is null.

[Here the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DfPK.png)
Please help me guru..

Comment: It may not work if your JSON.parse functions fails. Check console when you execute the AJAX

Comment: i try to check using debugger and check in console, i got the variable that i needed 
result.date --> "2021-04-13". Or is it a problem if the return still using " (quote)

Comment: Try to update your question by adding the response from the ajax call, in my case your code worked but with a proper response from ajax.

Comment: Already updated..

Comment: @gamingscout In your question you need to show us a code that reproduces the problem. If you're talking about returning a value after an asynchronous call, of course it's not going to work. By the time `success` function executes, the function that contains the Ajax call already returned.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can update the data from ajax response like this:

```js
$("#cohort_x1").attr("data-update", JSON.stringify({
    data: {
        datasets: [
            { data: result.data1 },
            { data: result.data2 }
        ]
    }
}));
```